# How to use printf to print spi data in stm32

Tags: stm32, spi

`printf()` can be used in UART data output, how about SPI data?
I rewrite the `fputc()` and using `hal_spi_transmite()`, will the data be printed via SPI?

```c
int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
{
    LoRa_transmit(&myLoRa, &send_data[i], 128, 500);
    return ch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> printf can be used in uart data output,how about SPI data?

I don't know exactly what `LoRa_transmit()` do but the data to be printed in this function is `int ch` and not `send_data[i]`:

```
int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
{
   LoRa_transmit(&myLoRa, &ch, 128, 500);
   return ch;
}
```

> will the data printed via spi?

It will work, but not as you expect (I guess) because of a few details:

1. SPI communication involves always one master and at least one slave device. The role cannot be changed because only the master device has control of the chip-select pin.
2. SPI protocols usually involve sending a control command before sending any data to the slave device.

So what will happen is that only the master device can use the "printf()" approach and it will only work if the slave device is expecting data like an input stream.

Supposing you call `printf("Hello SPI");`, the master device will start transmission (CS and clock), send the first byte of the string, close the transmission and repeat these steps until reaching the end of the string.